# How do we force a Chrome/Chromium desktop shortcut to open in its own window?

Tags: google-chrome, web, chromium

I added a desktop shortcut for `Google Photos` (http://photos.google.com), and I chose the `Open as window` option, and it works great: Google Photos always opens in its own window.

However, if I try to do the same thing with Google Calendar (http://calendar.google.com), it will never open in its own window even if I have selected the `Open as window` option.

Any ideas? Does it open in a new window for you? Maybe I need to clear some cache item. I already deleted the `.desktop` file from my Linux `~/.local/share/applications` folder and tried again, but no luck.

Note, the very first time I added Google Calendar, I did no select `Open as window`, so I wonder if maybe this setting is cached somewhere else and not in `~/.local/share/applications`.